# Extract surnames from a string with names in python

Tags: python, split

I have a string with names separated with the word "and" that are typed in two forms: "First Last" or "Last, First". I want to generate a list with just the surnames sorted alphabetically. 
I'm new to Python so I was wondering if there is a shorter or better way of doing what I've done:

```
names = 'John Foo and Baz, Mike Tom and Bar Foo, S. P.' 
authors  = [ i.strip() for i in names.split("and") ]
comma = [ i.split(',')[0] for i in [i for i in authors if "," in i] ]
nocomma = [ i.split()[-1] for i in [i for i in authors if not "," in i] ]
surnames = comma + nocomma
surnames.sort()
print surnames
```

Comment: Use codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you wanna do!?? What is the general form of the data!!?? Pleas be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact a few things you can improve:

- you should split by `' and '` to avoid splitting names that contain the letters `and` (this way,`trim` is no longer needed)
- the double `for` loop in your two list comprehensions is not needed
- if you move the `if` to the left of the list comprehension, you need only one of them

Finally, you can put the whole thing in one just slightly longer list comprehension, if you like:

```
surnames = sorted(i.split(",")[0] if "," in i else i.split()[-1]
                  for i in names.split(" and "))
```

Note, however, that this will still only work if persons with multiple surnames are written using the comma-separated style.

Comment: Excellent answer. I don't know why I got downvotes either. I believe the question was perfectly clear and I showed all the work that I had done before asking for help.